# Best way to find differences between two large arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance, algorithm

I have 2 very large arrays (of size ~2,500,000). I need to find difference between these arrays.
By difference I mean I need a resultant array with values that are in array 1 but not in array 2. I have used [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)() but it takes more than half an hour!

The first array is coming from one DB and second array from another db. They aren't on the same Database server. The arrays aren't of same size. I am dealing with huge number of mobile numbers. I need to find out those mobile numbers which are in one list, but aren't in another list

arrays are normal arrays with numeric keys. Diff code is as follows:

```
$numbers_list = array_diff($numbers_list, $some_other_list);
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Please help.

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with the internals of PHP, it seems likely that `array_diff()` has gone through several rounds of optimization and is probably going to be faster than any general array-difference function that you roll on your own.  If you gave us a better idea as to the structure of your data, there might be a quicker way to calculate differences for the particular arrays that you're looking at.  Or, as previous commenters have stated, you might want to take the diff from the database first.

Comment: If its numbers (real numbers, i.e, interpretable as integers) you should be able to `sort` them both, and loop through array 1, advancing the pointer with `next` in array 2 as long as value-in-2 < value-in-1, and so on. For this particular case, could be a lot faster.

Comment: In that case, it might be easier to dump the data from each db to a text file, and compare using a command-line tool like diff rather than trying it in PHP; or to do a dump from one db, load to a temporary table on the second, and use SQL to do the comparison.

Comment: If it's something you only need to do once, then copy one of the tables over to a temp table in the other database, do the query that gives you the diff, and be done with it.

Comment: can you use federated tables? that way you could join both tables in one db and call the result with a distinct.

Comment: @Gordon: federated tables are sloooow in a join, at least in MySQL in my experience. It has troubles using indexes too.

Comment: @Wrikken how about UNION then? the requirement right now is < 25 minutes :)

Comment: @Gordon: ugh, I'll whip out a test-db for that...

Comment: Thanks guys. It has come down to 2 and half minutes after I copied the second array into a temp table and got the difference through a SQL query.

Comment: The algorithm took **11 seconds**. Check the update in answer.

Comment: oops, it took 4 minutes 12 seconds to be exact. But nevertheless, it is better than before. Since it is kind of report generation task, one can wait for 5 minutes for it :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is the simple algorithm.

1. **Flip** 1st array. Values will become keys. So repeated values will be discarded.
2. **Flip** 2nd array (optional)
3. Check for each element in 2nd array if it exists in 1st array.

As you are working with very large arrays, it'll **consume a lot of memory**.

Here is my implementation,

```
$a = file("l.a"); // l.a is a file contains 2,500,000 lines
$b = file("l.b");

function large_array_diff($b, $a){
    // Flipping 
    $at = array_flip($a);
    $bt = array_flip($b); 
    // checking
    $d = array_diff_key($bt, $at);

    return array_keys($d);   
}
```

I ran it using **`4G`** memory limit. 3G also works. Just tested.

```
$ time php -d memory_limit=4G diff_la.php
```

It took about **11 seconds!**.

```
real    0m10.612s
user    0m8.940s
sys     0m1.460s
```

**UPDATE**

Following code runs **2x faster than `large_array_diff`** function stated above.

```
function flip_isset_diff($b, $a) {
    $at = array_flip($a);
    $d = array();
    foreach ($b as $i)
        if (!isset($at[$i])) 
            $d[] = $i;

    return $d;
}
```

Because it does not call `array_flip` (1 time), `array_diff_key` and `array_keys`. Lots of CPU cycles are saved due to this.

Comment: There are no duplicates in these arrays.

Comment: Even there is no duplicates, transposing will give ability to search using a *hash*.

Comment: Hmm, flipping it & array_diff_key is about 5 times faster then my method in the other answer, and about 30 times faster then a plain diff in testing here...

Comment: I did try the above mentioned steps but the time taken was above 20 minutes, so I closed the webpage in between to try for other alternatives.

Comment: Dont run it in the webpage, Run in console.

Comment: Thanks @Shiplu It came to be 40 seconds over-all and that is Just Awesome. Thanks again :) I might be doing some blunder earlier, so I re-wrote the complete code this time.

Comment: Your previous code runs 4 seconds faster than the current one. By previous I mean the following:

    public static function large_array_diff($b, $a){
    // transposing
    $at = array();
    foreach ($a as $i) {
        $at[$i] = 1;
    }

    // checking
    $d = array();

    foreach ($b as $i) {
        if (!isset($at[$i])) {
            $d[] = $i;
        }
    }
    return $d;   
}

Comment: @bluekant this updated code runs faster. It takes 9 seconds in my machine.

Answer (score 6):

OK, updated, casting to string for good measure (it makes a LOT of difference if we could use integers instead of strings...):

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
echo 'creating' . PHP_EOL;
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
for ($i = 0;$i < 2000000;$i++) {
    $array1[] = (string)rand(100000000, 999999999);
    $array2[] = (string)rand(100000000, 999999999);
}
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(true);
echo 'key diff flip' . PHP_EOL;
$array1f = array_flip($array1);
$array2f = array_flip($array2);
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(true);
echo 'key diff' . PHP_EOL;
$diff = array_diff_key($array1f, $array2f);
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(true);
echo 'sorting' . PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(true);
sort($array1);
sort($array2);
$notin2 = array();
reset($array2);
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'comparing' . PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    while (current($array2) < $value) {
        if (next($array2) == false) break;
    }
    if (current($array2) != $value) $notin2[] = $value;
}
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'plain diff' . PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(true);
$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Strings**

```
creating
8.66658186913
key diff flip
3.07359004021
key diff
1.48775887489
sorting
48.4047858715
comparing
9.41756916046
plain diff
19.21976614

real    1m37.574s
user    1m34.970s
sys     0m1.676s
```

**Integers**
(removed `(string)`):

```
creating
4.69975805283
key diff flip
2.5843539238
key diff
1.4868490696
sorting
15.2628200054
comparing
5.62516498566
plain diff
101.688895941

real    2m18.090s
user    2m15.112s
sys     0m1.356s
```

Much to my surprise..... `array_diff` hates integers it seems...

Comment: Yes, by all means, edit it to suit YOUR desired tab-width and whitespace-use. Djeez.