# Two arrays difference in php

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the two arrays dump

**1st array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T1
            [min_table] => 2
            [seat_per_table] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T2
            [min_table] => 2
            [seat_per_table] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T3
            [min_table] => 2
            [seat_per_table] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T4
            [min_table] => 2
            [seat_per_table] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T5
            [min_table] => 2
            [seat_per_table] => 4
        )

)
```

**2nd array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [table_no] => T5
        )

)
```

**Expected Array**

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [table_no] => T1
                [min_table] => 2
                [seat_per_table] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [table_no] => T2
                [min_table] => 2
                [seat_per_table] => 4
            )

)
```

I tried with `array_diff()`, but it doesn't give result.

Then tried with `unset()`,

```
foreach($example2 as $key => $value) {
   foreach($example1 as $key1 => $value1) {
      if ($value1 == $value) {
         unset($example2[$key])
      }
   }
}
```

this doesn't work.

How can i make this work properly?

Here i want to compare 'table_no' from array-1 and 'table_no' from array-2

Thanks.

Comment: These are object arrays.. You need to convert them to use before `array_diff()`

Comment: The objects in your two arrays are completely different.

Comment: Take a look at this thread. 
[Difference between two arrays in php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826908/best-way-to-find-differences-between-two-large-arrays-in-php

Comment: `array_diff()` only compares the string value of array elements. Unless your object has a toString method, you will need to write your own function. http://us3.php.net/array_diff

Comment: What do you expect as a result? Could you paste an example?

Comment: @BartekR check expected array...

Comment: I have edited my question please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it

```
foreach ($rest_tables as  $rtvalue){
    $res_rtable[]=$rtvalue->table_no;
}
foreach ($checklist as  $chvalue){
    $res_checklist[]=$chvalue->table_no;
}

$removeduplicate=array_intersect($res_rtable,$res_checklist);
$array_res = array_diff($res_rtable,$removeduplicate);

foreach($array_res as $key => $value){
    echo $value.'-'.$rest_tables[$key]->min_table.','.$rest_tables[$key]->seat_per_table.'<pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer will help you

```
$result = array_diff($first_array, $second_array);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're comparing by `table_no` in the first and `restaurant_table` in the second array?

Use [`array_udiff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php). It lets you use a callback to determine the difference between values. So for objects, where you don't necessarily want to just do `$someobj == $anotherobj`, it works well.

```
<?php

$t = new stdClass;
$t->table_no = 'T4';
$t2 = new stdClass;
$t2->table_no = 'T6';
$one = array(
    $t,
    $t2,
);

$t = new stdClass;
$t->restaurant_table = 'T4';
$two = array(
    $t,
);

$res = array_udiff($one, $two, function ($first, $second) {
    $no1 = isset($first->table_no) ? $first->table_no : (
        isset($first->restaurant_table) ? $first->restaurant_table : null
    );
    $no2 = isset($second->table_no) ? $second->table_no : (
        isset($second->restaurant_table) ? $second->restaurant_table : null
    );

    return strcmp($no1, $no2);
});

var_dump($res);
```

You're going to have a lot easier time doing this with objects that have the same property name for comparison.